# How can i fetch the value entered in input from a freemarker template to my Spring controller?

Tags: spring-mvc, freemarker

I have an input element in my Freemarker template.

```
<input type="text" name="tokenvalue" id="tokenvalue" value="" placeholder="Skriv inn token"></input>
```

How can i fetch the value entered in my input field out to my Controller?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/csv/import", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView importCVS(@RequestParam Optional<String> message, @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {

// Want the value entered in input out here

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add additional `@RequestParam` which expect `tokenvalue`:

```
@RequestParam("tokenvalue") String tokenvalue
```

Comment: I get this following error `ERROR: Required String parameter 'tokenvalue' is not present
Bad Request
org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required String parameter 'tokenvalue' is not present` , does not that tries to load the value from url params?

Comment: @mac187 it should be form parameter, how do you send it?

Comment: Its not wrapped in a form, its outside the form.